# Force screen to resize without window.open?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to use the specifications from the code below without the `windows.open`?

```
window.open("http://google.com.br", "_blank",
            "fullscreen=yes,location=no,menubar=no," +
            "resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,left=1," +
            "top=1,screenX=1,screenY=1,width=" + window.screen.width + ",height=" + window.screen.height);
});
```

I want to use this to my actual page:

```
"fullscreen=yes,location=no,menubar=no," +
"resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,left=1," +
"top=1,screenX=1,screenY=1,width=" + 
window.screen.width + ",height=" + window.screen.height
```

Comment: You can [change the size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo), but you can't get rid of toolbars etc on already open windows.

Comment: @JamesThorpe — See the **Notes** section of that page. Support for it has been removed. (Because it was horribly annoying before browsers started supporting tabs)

Comment: @Quentin Ah, ok - it's not something I've used myself for some time!

Comment: Got it, thanks guys.